# why Firebase in C# form app not realtime?

Tags: c#, firebase, fire-sharp

I'm trying to build an app that detects product from `android` and send it in real-time to the desktop application via firebase but I don't know `firebase` doesn't work in real-time when I get value on C# app (*I mean when I change values it doesn't change in the app automatically.*)

**Rq:** I'm using FireSharp reference and My code for receiving:

```
public void getdata()
  {
     var res = client.Get(@"Store/");
     Store str = res.ResultAs<Store>();
     store.Text = str.Tags;
     nb.Text = str.nb;
   }
```

Comment: So, you're getting something from your Firebase store, changing a value, and you are asking why it doesn't automatically update in Firebase too?  What do you mean that Firebase doesn't work in real-time?

Comment: I mean firebase at general changes your result when the database values changes. For example in android, we have public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) that execute automatically when data in firebase changes so U don't need to check by user self if data changes or not.

Answer (score 3):

By calling the [`Get` method](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp#get), you're calling the server to **get** the data only once.

If you want to instead get the data now and then continue to listen for updates, use the [`OnAsync` method](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp#listen-streaming-from-the-rest-api). From the linked documentation:

> ```
> EventStreamResponse response = await _client.OnAsync("chat", (sender, args, context) => {
>        System.Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
> });
>
> //Call dispose to stop listening for events
> response.Dispose();
> ```

Comment: Even I Use :
` private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IFirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(ifc);
            FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Store/");
            Store str = response.ResultAs<Store>(); //The response will contain the data being retreived
            store.Text = str.Tags;
            nb.Text = str.nb;
        }`
Text view don't Update automaticlly

Comment: If you use the code in my answer, does it print the new data in the console? Because if it does, you at least know that the database connection is getting its updates, and the problem is in the UI part of your code.

Comment: that's mean if I use it to update my local database it works fine?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried this but didn't work. Does the "chat"means the path ?

Comment: Yes, that is the path you are reading from.